# Use of unasigned local variable (string) error

Tags: c#, string, winforms, undefined

So i get this error at the textbox assignation but i don't understand why, can anyone give me an advice on what to do?

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox16.Text);
        int t = Convert.ToInt32(textBox17.Text);
        matrix.CalculeazaQR(n, t);

        string temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                temp = matrix.q[i, j].ToString("0.00");

                if (j % (n - 1) == 0)
                    temp += "\n";

                temp += ",";

            }

        }
        textBox3.Text = temp;

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You are assigning `temp` inside the for loop and compiler can't determine whether you will get inside the loop or not. You may initialize the `temp` on top like:

```
string temp = string.Empty;
```

Statements inside the loop would only execute if the condition is true and the compiler at compile time can't determine whether the condition will be true or not, it will consider the temp to remain unassigned,  hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

put like this:

```
string temp="";
```

you have to assign string(or any variable) to empty or something before you actually use it.

Comment: *"you have to assign string to empty **when you declare it**"*
Actually, you don't. Only when using the variable later on you'll need to have it assigned a value *before* using the variable. `string temp; temp = "foo"; Console.WriteLine(temp);`. No assignment on declaration, still works. This is because the compiler can determine with 100% certainty that, before *temp* is used, it will be assigned a value. Also works: `string temp; if (a==b) temp = "foo" else temp = "bar"; Console.WriteLine(foo);` because in either case of the `if`-statement foo will be assigned a value.

Answer (score 1):

*"can anyone give me an advice on what to do?"*
Well, Initialize text:

```
string temp = string.Empty;
```

The compiler has no way of knowing if temp (which is used on `textBox3.Text = temp;`) has a value after the loops (for instance, when n < 1).

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, your loop is broken to start with - only the very last iteration will matter (i.e. when both `i` and `j` are `n - 1`) as you're replacing the value of `temp` completely.

But the compiler doesn't know that `n` is positive - it doesn't know that you'll *ever* get into the loop. In general, the compiler will never assume that you enter the body of an `if` statement, a `for` statement, a `while` statement or a `foreach` loop - so any assignments made within those bodies don't affect whether a local variable is *definitely assigned* or not at the end of the statement... and a local variable has to be definitely assigned before you can read from it (as you're doing at the end of the method).

I suspect you actually want a `StringBuilder` which you append to within the loop:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (...)
{
    for (...)
    {
        builder.AppendFormat("{0:0.00},", matrix.q[i, j]);            
    }
    builder.Append("\n");
}
textBox3.Test = builder.ToString();
```